# Visual Studio App Center - Remove unprovisioned devices / re-sign manually?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I have some users who have added some devices and I don't want to register them with as the apple developer device or have them part of the provisioning profile.  Is there a way to remove unprovisioned apple devices?  I am getting dangerously close to the 100 mark and I have 1 device that I do need to register with the app center.  The alternative question would be is there a way to update the provisioning profile without letting app center do the registration?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I feel like I have to be missing something. Seems so basic to be able to remove the devices I don’t want having access to the app or don’t want to register with apple prior to resigning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there is no way to do either of things mentioned in my question.  The AppCenter team is going to be looking at adding these features in the near future.

Follow the feature request here:
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/951

Answer (score 1):

You can remove devices. You have to go to  Account settings -> My Devices -> choose a device and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for everyone but I was able to work around this limitation of AppCenter by deleting the Tester from the Distribution Group.  The Unprovisioned devices associated with that Tester were also removed from the Distribution Group.